Keeping form data when using browser-back after submit with HTMX
I am learning HTMX, and in the process I have a page with a form. When a valid form is submitted, the application should "redirect" to a new page.
A typical classical server-side rendering approach to this problem would implement the following POST handling logic:

Validate the form. If not valid, render the same page with validation errors
Delegate to relevant business logic to update data.
Respond with a 302 (which really should be a 303 today) and a location header to redirect to.

The browser would then issue a GET request for the new URL, showing the target page. If the user used the browser-back function, the old page would be shown from cache with the form filled out with what the user had typed before submitting.
For some use cases, this works very well from a UX point of view. If the user had made a mistake, they can press back, update the contents of the form, and submit it again. An example use case where this works well is when you are updating an existing resource, and there is no risk of concurrent updates to that resource from other users.
I want to achieve the same behaviour using HTMX. It almost works as intended, but when using browser-back, the form is empty, instead of filled out with the previous values.
How do I get the browser to keep the values of the form after a browser-back in this case?
Is there an idiomatic HTMX approach to handling form submission, when you want to "redirect" to a new page on success?
Current HTMX solution
The form has the following attributes:
<form hx-post="/form" hx-swap="outerHTML">
</form>

hx-swap is used for the case of validation errors, where the HTTP response contains a "new" form with validation errors and input fields filled out with previously submitted values.
In case of a valid form post, the server does the following:

Response with a 303 status code
Set the HX-Push-Url response header
Render the contents of the target page in the response body.

Using the location header, which I would have assumed to be more "correct", leads to weird issues.
node.js/express code
router.post("/form", (req, res) => {
  // ... stuff
  // If successful, this runs
    res
      .status(303)
      .header("HX-Push-Url", "/new-page")
      .render("new-page");
})

The HTML templates have a <div id="body-root" hx-swap-oob="true"> element on both pages, i.e. the form page and the new page "redirected" to.
Working non-HTMX code
The classic server-rendered approach would be changing the form to:
<form method="POST" target="/form">
</form>
```html

And change the request handler to

```javascript
router.post("/form", (req, res) => {
  // ... stuff
  // If successful
    res
      .status(303)
      .location("/new-page")
      .send();

This results in the form-behaviour I expect, but with the flash of reload I wanted to avoid with HTMX.
